# Fatal error: Out of memory in WordPress running on AWS EC2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

I launch an instance (EC2): Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM), SSD Volume Type
all the options are default (free tier)
In installed Wordpress and run it online for test.

I configured as bellow :
sudo vim /etc/php.ini (php.ini file)

> `memory_limit = 1024M`

I added two line in wp-config.php

> `define('FS_METHOD','direct');` 
> `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');`

Using .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_php7.c>
php_value memory_limit 1024M
</IfModule>
```

But sometimes I still get the error messages like:

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 28311552) (tried to allocate
> 65536 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

or

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 24117248) (tried to allocate
> 143360 bytes) in file...

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Please help?
In php.ini file I see 
`; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)`
`; http://php.net/memory-limit` 
before line 
`memory_limit = 1024M`
Is that mean even I set memory_limit = 1024M the memory limit still is 128MB on EC2?

Comment: Usually when those error happens it means that something with bad performance is running into your code. Of course, maybe increasing it somehow would silence the error but the problem may still be there. Inspect your code and look for time-consuming scripts

Comment: This site is for programming-specific questions. Questions about WordPress administration, server configuration, etc. are off topic and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try adding this line to your wp-config.php file:

`define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');`

2. If you have access to your PHP.ini file, change the line in PHP.ini

`memory_limit = 1024M;`

3. Using htacess.

`php_value memory_limit 1024M`

PS: Try restarting the PHP service as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your wordpress needs more memory to run than you have given, which is 256M.
Now solution is to optimize your wordpress like remove un-necessary plugins / themes etc. Use proper caching and CDN. But if still it gives error then try to increase the instance type to next level. Like from t2.nano to t2.micro

Comment: Thank you Atiqur,
I see
`; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit`
before line
`memory_limit = 1024M`
Is that mean even I set `memory_limit = 1024M` the memory limit still is 128MB?

Comment: If you ec2 instance Memory is 512MB then changing the value in php.ini to 1024MB wouldn't affect that much. Because your instance can't allocate more than 512MB memory to your script. Also linux system requires some memory for itself.